# which thread to launch JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing

We have a Swing application with socket communication and other threads. We know we need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to update Swing display from other threads. But how about `JOptionPane`? do we need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` from other threads to launch `JOptionPane`?

if the answwer is yes, how to use JOptionPane to block the procedure?

if the answer is no, doesn't JOptionPane belong to GUI display?

Comment: `SwingUtilities#invokeAndWait`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if the answwer is yes, how to use JOptionPane to block the procedure

The answer is indeed yes. You should access/modify/... all Swing components on the Event Dispatch Thread. So your background thread needs to use some mechanism to call the `JOptionPane` on the EDT. Using `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` is an option, but not a blocking one.

Use `SwingUtilities#invokeAndWait` for the blocking behavior. This method will wait until the runnable is finished before returning.

Comment: +1 I didn't realize the question could be interpreted 2 ways until I read your comment on the question.  The OP probably meant it your way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to launch the JOptionPane - otherwise the JOptionPane may not be responsive.  Since it's a modal container, it should block input to the main container by default. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html for more details.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question.  I was thinking you wanted the JOptionPane to block user input on the parent frame.  If you want the JOptionPane to block further execution of a program, you'll need to use Robin's suggestion:  SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()  - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait(java.lang.Runnable)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, you have to call swing components only from the EventQueue. Have a look at [Is JOptionPane.showMessageDialog thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595744/is-joptionpane-showmessagedialog-thread-safe)