# A very unclear error that sometimes interrupts my thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, interrupted-exception

I know that I should provide with enough information for a special bug. But it is not possible to reproduce it. I have a highly multithreaded program. I have a thread with an infinite while loop. No part of the program can interrupt this thread. I check `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();` as much as I can.
 But sometimes it happens that thread stops running with a strange exception stack trace that tells it can't convert some type to Boolean in the setText mehod of some Lable and it points to the following line of the programme:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "action finished, going to the next!");
```

I know that I should think differently! because I have no label to set the text which is done in this thread. In fact in the whole program I never change any text of the GUI. I just write to the console. What can be the problem? Can it be a memory leak in my code or it might be a bug of Java?

Comment: Are you calling `showMessageDialog` directly, or giving it to a Swing worker to execute (or using `invokeLater`?)

Comment: Directly! without a swing worker!

Comment: Basic rule of SO: If you're asking about an exception, POST THE ENTIRE STACK TRACE, and the code that throws the exception.

Comment: The stacktrace I can't reproduce! Sorry! It happened to me twice. The code I can copy the code but I'm sure that it will mess up the question. Because it is highly complicated. In nutshell the programme controls industrial machines. I have no software simulator and I only can try the code when I connect the computer to industrial machines(robots). I have told that I might not be able to reproduce stack trace and it refers to no place in my code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you're not supposed to invoke `showMessageDialog` directly. Swing expects that all GUI operations go through the main Swing thread, and [as reported in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595744/is-joptionpane-showmessagedialog-thread-safe) I suspect that the issue here is a race condition between your thread (which shouldn't do touching the GUI directly) and the Swing thread (which is supposed to handle this).

You may want to consider firing off `showMessageDialog` from a `SwingWorker` or by using `invokeLater`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I try to cover all the swing dialog messages in swing job queues and I will report if the error will be seen in the next days.

Comment: Todayy I tested the programme many times and you had pointed the problem correctly! invokeLater is inevitable. Now I think about a wrapper which shows a message box in a new thread.